# How do i choose a background gradient from an array?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I am trying to make a background gradient be set randomly by a onload function but it does not execute somewhere in the code.

```
<html>
  <script>
    const g = [
  "color: blue; linear-gradient(to top, #e0eafc, #cfdef3);",
  "color:purple; linear-gradient(to top, #eecda3, #ef629f);",
  "color: green; linear-gradient(to top, #00d2ff, #928dab);"
];

    
    function rg() { document.body.style.background = g[Math.floor(Math.random()*g.length)];
    }

  </script>

<body onload="rg()">
    <h1>Game Library</h1>
    <div class="game">
      <a href="/games/1"><img src="/icons/game1.png" alt="Game 1"></a>
      <p>Madalin stunt cars 2</p>
    </div>
  </body>

<style>
    body {
  font-family: custom;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;

}
</style>
</html>
```

I got a white background, I was expecting a gradient.

Comment: your HTML is invalid as you have it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to have a valid value for the css, and the gradient needs to come first:

```js
const g = [
  "linear-gradient(to top, #e0eafc, #cfdef3), blue",
  "linear-gradient(to top, #eecda3, #ef629f), purple",
  "linear-gradient(to top, #00d2ff, #928dab), green"
];

    
function rg() { 
    const i = Math.floor(Math.random()*g.length)
    document.querySelector('body').style.background = g[i];
}
```

```html
<body onload="rg()">
    <h1>Game Library</h1>
    <div class="game">
      <a href="/games/1"><img src="/icons/game1.png" alt="Game 1"></a>
      <p>Madalin stunt cars 2</p>
    </div>
  </body>

<style>
    body {
  font-family: custom;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;

}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The css gradients in the array are not in the correct syntax.
Replace the array with the correct css syntax for the gradient:

```
    const g = [
      "linear-gradient(to top, #e0eafc, #cfdef3)",
      "linear-gradient(to top, #eecda3, #ef629f)",
      "linear-gradient(to top, #00d2ff, #928dab)"
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem was in including color (Font color) on the array element strings but on `function rg()` you asked to set `document.body.style.background` instead of `document.body.style`.
Consider the following code:

```
<script>
    const g = [
      "background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #e0eafc, #cfdef3);color: blue",
      "background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #eecda3, #ef629f);color: purple",
      "background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #00d2ff, #928dab); color: green"
    ];

        
    function rg() { 
        document.querySelector('body').style = g[Math.floor(Math.random()*g.length)];
    }

</script>

    <body onload="rg()">
        <h1>Game Library</h1>
        <div class="game">
          <a href="/games/1"><img src="/icons/game1.png" alt="Game 1"></a>
          <p>Madalin stunt cars 2</p>
        </div>
      </body>

    <style>
        body {
      font-family: custom;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 100%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-attachment: fixed;

    }
    </style>
```

This changes the "color" also according to the given combination of gradient and color.

Answer (score 0):

With valid HTML and some slight alteration to put it on the two properties it can work.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    const g = [
      "blue; linear-gradient(to top, #e0eafc, #cfdef3)",
      "purple; linear-gradient(to top, #eecda3, #ef629f)",
      "green; linear-gradient(to top, #00d2ff, #928dab)"
    ];

    function rg() {
      let getme = g[Math.floor(Math.random() * g.length)];
      let bcolor = getme.split('; ');
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = bcolor[0];
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = bcolor[1];
    }
  </script>

  <style>
    body {
      font-family: custom;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 100%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-attachment: fixed;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body onload="rg()">
  <h1>Game Library</h1>
  <div class="game">
    <a href="/games/1"><img src="/icons/game1.png" alt="Game 1"></a>
    <p>Madalin stunt cars 2</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```